# During installation of Django, why do I keep getting ImportError: No module named django?

Tags: python, django, macos, installation

I'm just trying to get a "hello world" using django.  I've downloaded django onto my desktop and i have python with Idle in my applications folder.  I've followed the instructions on https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ but when i try to `import django` in Idle I get `ImportError: No module named django`

I've looked around and have tried `sys.path` which yields `['', '/Users/nicholastzikas/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

I've also seen `PYTHONPATH` mentioned a few times, but I have no idea how to use this.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any errors during `python setup.py install`?

Comment: Not that I remember.  I had an error when installing django that I had previously downloaded it, but I removed the previous django and re-downloaded it without error.

Comment: how many files have you enlisted in your python path?

Comment: My Idle also seems to work fine.  I have an older Mac OS X 10.6.8 .  Could that be an issue?

Comment: @mangobug I'm not sure what u mean.  I don't believe I've intentionally enlisted any files.

Comment: just type `python` on your console  and there type `import django` - does it import successfully ?

Comment: @karthikr if I type `python` it returns `NameError: name 'python' is not defined`.  If I type `import django` ir returns `ImportError: No module named django`.  If I type `2+2` it returns `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the path where django got installed to is somehow not in any of the paths listed in your `sys.path`. Normally it should be inside of site-packages. What you could try is the following:

1) Search for the dir where django was installed on your system.

2) once you find it, you can quickly test if that is the problem, adding in IDLE the path with `sys.path.append('/path/to/django/dir')` and then try `import django` again.

3.a) If that worked, you can manually move the path to `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` for example.

3.b) If that doesn't work, well, then maybe the django files are corrupted (try installing again) or maybe the versions of your installed python and django mismatch?

Comment: Nice.  I didn't quite do it the same way u suggested, but ur idea was correct.  For some reason if the django folder was in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` and not `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` where Idle was looking.  I merely copied and pasted folder into the directory where Idle looks and KAZAMM! I think it's working.

Comment: Ah, looks like you are using the EPD Python 2.7 distribution.  They use different directory layouts. It would have helped to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.  First, if you haven't restarted IDLE since you installed django, try quitting IDLE (Command-Q) and restarting it.  If that doesn't help, chances are that you inadvertently installed Django to another Python instance, probably one of the Apple-supplied system Pythons.  Just try it again: quit IDLE again then, from a new Terminal shell window, install Django again but make sure you are using `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` rather than just `python`.

Comment: Ok not sure of this is what u intended but I uninstalled django, than reinstalled it typing `sudo python2.7 setup.py install` into my terminal.  instead of `sudo python setup.py install`.  It installed, but the same `ImportError: No module named django` problem persists.

Comment: Try `sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py install`