# Django Installation Error (No Module Named Django)

Tags: python, django, directory, installation

I am using Mac OS X Mavericks.

I have an error with installing Django. Using the "pip install" command I installed Django. It is in the directory below.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

When I type "python" into the command line, and then "import django", it says No Module Named Django.

Based on reading other answers, apparently sys.path will say which directories I can install Django in.

So I did:

```
import sys
for x in sys.path: print x
```

This gives the following list of directories:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.0.1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.7.3-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/modulegraph-0.10.4-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

So clearly my pip install Django is not going in the right directory.

How can I use pip install to put Django in one of those directories?

There is a somewhat similar question here: [During installation of Django, why do I keep getting ImportError: No module named django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857247/during-installation-of-django-why-do-i-keep-getting-importerror-no-module-name?rq=1) . The answer recommends adding the directory to the path using sys.path.append('insert path here') but I'm not sure if this is a good way of solving the problem.

Comment: are you using virtualenv? if so are you in your virtualenv? if not, you probably should.

Comment: how can I tell if I am using virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Well for anyone else with this problem who is still confused how virtualenv and all that stuff works, and may have installed too many incompatible versions: The simple fix is to just download the tar.gz from the Django downloads page and follow the instructions they gave:

```
tar xzvf Django-1.6.1.tar.gz
cd Django-1.6.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Try --user while using pip ( which gives admin privilege)

`pip install --user django`

Comment: this works perfectly on OS X. I also recommend previously fully uninstall django.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install virtual env to overcome this problem. Read about [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), its a nice one.

Comment: i'm having trouble using it, it says "/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper"virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.

Comment: I haven't used Mac, but as far as I know, its Unix based system, so will tell solution based on the fact. cd to /usr/bin there you will see files named as python and python2 (or python3 based on your version you installed). These files must be a symbolic link to files python2.7 (or python3.3). Delete those files and recreate the symbolic links. To do this you would be requiring super user permissions.